# Обновление GUI из другого потока

Tags: c#, gui, winforms, сниппет

Подскажите простой способ, как можно обновить label из другого потока?

Ситуация следующая: имеется окно (поток1), в котором стартует новый поток (поток2). Когда поток2 обрабатывает файлы, необходимо обновить label на форме, используя информацию из потока2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте `BeginInvoke`. Вот пример из [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx#Y950)

```
public delegate void InvokeDelegate();

private void Invoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myTextBox.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(InvokeMethod));
}
public void InvokeMethod()
{
   myTextBox.Text = "Executed the given delegate";
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
myTextBox.Invoke(new Action(() => { myTextBox.Text = "Обновляем данные"; }));
```

Answer (score 3):

Так пишут по-пацански (если без async, конечно):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    new Thread(_ => {
        sync.Post(__ =>
            label.Text = "Clicked!", null);
    }).Start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно еще так:

```
var settextAction = new Action(() => { myTextBox.Text = "Обновляем данные"; });
if (myTextBox.InvokeRequired)
   myTextBox.Invoke(settextAction); 
else
   settextAction();
```

Answer (score 2):

На формочках рекомендуется обычно использовать BackgroundWorker.