# Недопустима операция в нескольких потоках: Доступ к элементу, не из того потока в котором он был создан

Tags: c#, winforms

Проблема, пытаюсь сделать потоковый вывод из терминала. Выдает следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ServerLog - это RichTextBox. С обычным лейблом это тоже не работает.
Посоветуйте решение новичку пожалуйста.

```
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Process ServerM = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo StartConf = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/c ipconfig \"",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
        };


        public void ServerStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServerM.StartInfo = StartConf;
            ServerM.Start();
            ServerM.BeginOutputReadLine();
            ServerM.OutputDataReceived += (s, a) => {
                ServerLog.AppendText(a.Data + "\n");
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11861/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-gui-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ты пытаешься вызвать или изменить свойства контролла из другого потока можно использовать Invoke
Пример:

```
ServerLog.Invoke(new Action(()=>ServerLog.AppendText(a.Data+"\n")));
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, ломал голову несколько часов, помог дилетанту.

Comment: Та всегда пожалуйста, там тебе человек выше в коммент отправлял такую же ссылку на такое же решение ))